# Sigma-protocol for 3SAT problem

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, protocol-design, sigma-protocol

I have some questions from previous years exams, I hope you could help me with them. :)

Let $g,h$ denote generators of a group $G$ of large prime order $n$ such that $\log_g h$ is unknown to anyone. Consider an instance of the 3SAT problem for Boolean variables $v_1, \ldots , v_l$, given by a Boolean formula $\Phi$ consisting of $m$ clauses, which each consist of $3$ literals:

$ \Phi = (l_{1,1} \vee l_{1,2} \vee l_{1,3}) \wedge \ldots \wedge (l_{m,1} \vee l_{m,2} \vee l_{m,3})$.

Each literal is of the form $l_{i,j}=v_k$ or $l_{i,j}=\overline{v_k}=1-v_k$ (negation of $v_k$), $1 \le k \le l$. Construct a $\Sigma$-protocol for the following relation:

$R_{\Phi}=\{ (B_1, \ldots, B_l;x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_l,y_l)\colon \Phi(x_1,\ldots,x_l), \forall_{k=1}^l B_k=g^{x_k}h^{y_k}, x_k \in \{ 0,1 \} \}$.

Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Could you add the definition of $\Sigma$-protocol?

Comment: Welcome to Crypto.SE!  This looks like an interesting question, but it would help to have a little more information.  What have you tried so far?  What research have you done on your own so far?  As the [faq#do-we-accept-basic-levelhomework-questions] suggests, [it is important to "do your homework" and show us what you've done so far](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask).  I encourage you to read the links in this comment -- they may provide helpful background about this site!

Comment: The question is an exercise from Chapter 5 of [Lecture Notes Cryptographic Protocols](https://www.win.tue.nl/~berry/CryptographicProtocols/LectureNotes.pdf). Since February 2019, full solutions to all exercises are included at the back of these lecture notes.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable by
(1) opening all commitments $B_k$ with standard responses $Q_{k}(z)$ that are linear in challenge,
(2) proving that all $x_k \in \{0,1\}$ (with at most second-degree polynomials in challenge), and
(3) proving $m$ polynomial identities for (at most) third-degree polynomials in challenge
$$U_i(z) = T_{i,1}(z) T_{i,2}(z) T_{i,3}(z) $$
where
$T_{i,j}(z) = Q_{i,j}(z) - z l_{i,j}$ and
$Q_k(z) = v_k z + \alpha_k$
considered over the ring modulo group order and
$\alpha_k$ are initial random coins.

With such a $\Sigma$-like protocol, prover will send commitments to 3 coefficients of polynomials $U_k(z)$.
It is actually proven that such a polynomial is of 2nd degree, not 3rd.
Informally, we need at least one TRUE out of each triple for satifstiability,
so at least one constant (degree 0) polynomial for each $(T_{i,1}(z), T_{i,2}(z), T_{i,3}(z))$.
The well-known $\Sigma$-protocol would evaluate a linear (degree 1) polynomial at a random point chosen as a challenge.

(Soundness) For any (that is, dishonest) prover, there are at most 3 chances (unlike just 1 for the well-known $\Sigma$-protocol) for such a polynomial to evaluate to zero by choosing some random value for the free variable $z$.
See Schwartz-Zippel lemma for details.

One would choose the challenge from a large set comparable to (large) group order.
Or maybe from polylog-cardinality set for zero knowledge.

For point (2), one would prove that $Q_k(z) (Q_k(z) - z)$ is linear (not quadratic) by sending commitments to two coefficients.